# Data from one list to another in java

Tags: java

I have two list created from class.

One is called Budget, with elements section, month and sum, which return this:

[Budzet{sec='AGD/RTV', month='01', sum=96}, Budzet{sec='AGD/RTV',month='03', sum=30}, Budzet{sec='Food', month='04', sum=23}, Budzet{sec='Game', month='09', sum=1084} ... ]

This is SQL query

```
"SELECT SUM(cena) AS suma, dzial, add_data FROM products2021 WHERE wartosc='ujemna' GROUP BY dzial, EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM add_data)
```

and second with elements section, jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug,sep, oct, nov, dec.

I would like to assign the value of the sum from the first list to the second according to the months and to a particular session. And in months where there is no value to display 0. I can't handle it.

I would like to display my data like this:

AGD/TRV{ jul=0, oct=0, feb=0, apr=0, jun=96, aug=0, dec=0, nov=0, may=0, jan=0, mar=30, sep=0}

Food { jul=0, oct=0, feb=0, apr=23, jun=0, aug=0, dec=0, nov=0, may=0, jan=0, mar=0, sep=0}

Game { ul=0, oct=0, feb=0, apr=0, jun=0, aug=0, dec=0, nov=0, may=0, jan=0, mar=0, sep=1084}

Witch division on section

Comment: I've included a second solution to achieve your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> {jul=0, oct=0, feb=0, apr=23, jun=0, aug=0, dec=0, nov=0, may=0,
> jan=96, mar=30, sep=1084}

1. Create a map of month numbers (keys) and initial sums (values). // 'monthSums'.
2. Loop through your dataset ('budzets') while updating the 'monthSums' map values.
3. Replace the keys of the 'monthSums' map with their respective month labels ('monthLabels').

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Budzet {
    String sec;
    String month;
    Integer sum;

    public Budzet(String sec, String month, Integer sum) {
        this.sec = sec;
        this.month = month;
        this.sum = sum;
    }
}

class Scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Budzet> budzets = Arrays.asList(
                new Budzet("AGD/RTV", "01", 96),
                new Budzet("AGD/RTV", "03", 30),
                new Budzet("Food", "04", 23),
                new Budzet("Game", "09", 1084)
        );

        List<String> monthLabels = Arrays.asList("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec");

        // 1. Create a map of month numbers (keys) and initial sums (values). // 'monthSums'.
        Map<String, Integer> monthSums = IntStream
                .rangeClosed(1, monthLabels.size())
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> (i < 10 ? "0" + i.toString() : i.toString()), i -> 0));

        // 2. Loop through your dataset ('budzets') while updating the 'monthSums' map values.
        for (Budzet budzet : budzets) {
            monthSums.put(budzet.month, monthSums.get(budzet.month) + budzet.sum);
        }

        // 3. Replace the keys of the 'monthSums' map with their respective month labels (monthLabels).
        monthSums = monthSums
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> monthLabels.get(Integer.parseInt(e.getKey()) - 1), Map.Entry::getValue));

        System.out.println(monthSums);
        // {jul=0, oct=0, feb=0, apr=23, jun=0, aug=0, dec=0, nov=0, may=0, jan=96, mar=30, sep=1084}

    }
}
```

##### Addendum

***[Edit]***

> AGD/TRV{ jul=0, oct=0, feb=0, apr=0, jun=96, aug=0, dec=0, nov=0,
> may=0, jan=0, mar=30, sep=0}
>
> Food { jul=0, oct=0, feb=0, apr=23, jun=0, aug=0, dec=0, nov=0, may=0,
> jan=0, mar=0, sep=0}
>
> Game { ul=0, oct=0, feb=0, apr=0, jun=0, aug=0, dec=0, nov=0, may=0,
> jan=0, mar=0, sep=1084}

In response to your new result output expectation, you could achieve it this way:

1. Create a map of month numbers (keys) and initial sums (values). // 'monthSums'.
2. Create a map of 'budzet.sec' (keys) and 'monthSums'. // 'resultMap'.
3. Loop through your dataset ('budzets') while updating the 'resultMap' map values ('monthSums').
4. Replace the keys of the 'monthSums' map with their respective month labels ('monthLabels') in the 'resultMap'.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Budzet {
    String sec;
    String month;
    Integer sum;

    public Budzet(String sec, String month, Integer sum) {
        this.sec = sec;
        this.month = month;
        this.sum = sum;
    }
}

class Scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Budzet> budzets = Arrays.asList(
                new Budzet("AGD/RTV", "01", 96),
                new Budzet("AGD/RTV", "03", 30),
                new Budzet("Food", "04", 23),
                new Budzet("Game", "09", 1084)
        );

        List<String> monthLabels = Arrays.asList("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec");

        // 1. Create a map of month numbers (keys) and initial sums (values). // 'monthSums'.
        Map<String, Integer> monthSums = IntStream
                .rangeClosed(1, monthLabels.size())
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> (i < 10 ? "0" + i.toString() : i.toString()), i -> 0));


        // 2. Create a map of 'budzet.sec' (keys) and 'monthSums'. // 'resultMap'.
        // 3. Loop through your dataset ('budzets') while updating the 'resultMap' map values ('monthSums').
        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (Budzet budzet : budzets) {
            if (!resultMap.containsKey(budzet.sec)) {
                resultMap.put(budzet.sec, new HashMap<>(monthSums));
            }

            Map<String, Integer> value = resultMap.get(budzet.sec);
            value.put(budzet.month, value.get(budzet.month) + budzet.sum);

            resultMap.put(budzet.sec, value);
        }

        // 4. Replace the keys of the 'monthSums' map with their respective month labels ('monthLabels') in the 'resultMap'.
        resultMap = resultMap
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .peek(e -> e.setValue(e.getValue()
                        .entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> monthLabels.get(Integer.parseInt(i.getKey()) - 1), Map.Entry::getValue))))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

        System.out.println(resultMap);
        // {AGD/RTV={jul=0, oct=0, feb=0, apr=0, jun=0, aug=0, dec=0, nov=0, may=0, jan=96, mar=30, sep=0}, Game={jul=0, oct=0, feb=0, apr=0, jun=0, aug=0, dec=0, nov=0, may=0, jan=0, mar=0, sep=1084}, Food={jul=0, oct=0, feb=0, apr=23, jun=0, aug=0, dec=0, nov=0, may=0, jan=0, mar=0, sep=0}}

    }
}
```